# Difference between して and したり

Tags: grammar, て-form

What is the difference between saying 「最近毎日は何もをしなかったり、ただの寝るとからなるよ。」and「最近毎日は何もをしなくて、ただの寝るのよ。」

I'm not sure if one doesn't work with that sentence, or if this works the same in negative form, but I've been seeing the past-tense + り combination quite a bit recently and just wanted to know which to use and when.

Comment: Where are these sentences from?  Did you come up with them yourself?

Comment: Both Japanese sentences make no sense to me... What are you trying to say?

Comment: Ah sorry yeah I made these up, still not very good at Japanese. I was trying to say 'Lately my days consist of not doing anything, then just going to sleep.'

Comment: @Genzou Then I'd say 最近の毎日はごろごろしてから寝て終わり. I'm jealous of you...

Comment: @broccoli forest Oh ok I definitely wouldn't have though of that, thanks. Also, if you're talking about being jealous of me because of the sentence then that's just an example, I'm plenty busy enough haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

したり is commonly used when enumerating verbs that you do in no particular order.
（例：僕の趣味は映画を見たり、本を読んだりすることです。）

It can also mean "and the like" depending on the context. If only one verb is mentioned, I usually interpret it as "and the like." For example, even just the first part of sentence below already gives an idea that the speaker hasn't done anything productive and has been only slacking and sleeping a lot recently .
「**最近毎日は何もをしなかったり**、ただの寝るとからなるよ。」

Hope this helps.

Comment: The last example has some errors. What is the last part supposed to mean?